# Not allowed to return a result set from a function

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a function which return the sum of all my Top Sales but I am getting this error.

```
DELIMITER ++

CREATE FUNCTION CostOfBestBuyers(number INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
    SELECT SUM(Tprice)
      FROM (SELECT SUM(T.Quantity * S.ProductPrice) AS Tprice
              FROM Transaction T JOIN Stocks S ON T.ProductCode = S.ProductCode
          GROUP BY UserCode ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT number) AS subquery; 
END++

DELIMITER ;
```

The SQL statement alone returns a single value but when I put the query in the function, it comes back with an error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Bad practice to name your aliases the same as built in SQL function names, by the way

Comment: Wait, query itself works but when you put it in function, it doesn't work anymore? Did you try creating a procedure instead?

Comment: The Error message was ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a function !

Comment: Thank you @EatPeanutButter! I will change that!

Comment: @wast Yea but my task was to create a function. When I create a procedure with the same parameters, my queries worked as well! I just can't seem to get it to work in a function

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a result-set with an unbounded `SELECT`, which functions don't support.  You need to return a scalar value.  To get a scalar value from a query, you need to write it as a scalar subquery and use the `RETURN` statement to return its value:

```
DELIMITER ++

CREATE FUNCTION CostOfBestBuyers(number INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT SUM(Sum)
      FROM (SELECT SUM(T.Quantity * S.ProductPrice) AS Sum
              FROM Transaction T JOIN Stocks S ON T.ProductCode = S.ProductCode
          GROUP BY UserCode ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT number) AS subquery
  ); 
END++

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your advice. But what I am confused about it, the SUM(Tprice) should return a scalar value. However, to get T Price I will have to call out a column set of rows to add them up. And the Limit of the number of rows will depend on the parameter input by the user with the input "number" So I guess my problem will be the result sets produced by my subqueries. How can I get around with this?

Comment: `SELECT SUM(c1) FROM t1` returns a result set with exactly one row and one column, which is similar to, but not precisely the same thing as, a scalar value. Wrapping it in parentheses `(SELECT SUM(c1) FROM t1)` converts it to a scalar subquery that evaluates as a scalar value.

Comment: To oversimplify the example, if you wanted to return the current date/time from a stored function, you can do that with `RETURN NOW();` but you **cannot** do it with `SELECT NOW();` ... but you **can** do it with `RETURN (SELECT NOW());` because the parentheses convert the one row one column result from the `SELECT` into a scalar value.  (You wouldn't do that unnecessary work with such a simple return value, of course, but it is valid.  This is to illustrate the principle.)

Comment: *"I guess my problem will be the result sets produced by my subqueries."*  To be clear... no.  Your only problem is failing to make the somewhat subtle distinction between a 1-row × 1-column result set and a true scalar value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just missing a RETURN

```
DELIMITER ++

CREATE FUNCTION CostOfBestBuyers(number INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN 
    RETURN SELECT SUM(Sum)
      FROM (SELECT SUM(T.Quantity * S.ProductPrice) AS Sum
              FROM Transaction T JOIN Stocks S ON T.ProductCode = S.ProductCode
          GROUP BY UserCode ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT number) AS subquery; 
END++

DELIMITER ;
```